# Pyramid with Jinja2 running Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, jinja2

I can't make Jinja2 2.8 work with Pyramid 1.4.2 and Python 3.3.2. I got this error:

`File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Jinja2-2.8_devdev_20130604-py3.3.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 765, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Jinja2-2.8_devdev_20130604-py3.3.egg/jinja2/loaders.py", line 119, in load
    bucket = bcc.get_bucket(environment, name, filename, source)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Jinja2-2.8_devdev_20130604-py3.3.egg/jinja2/bccache.py", line 176, in get_bucket
    key = self.get_cache_key(name, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Jinja2-2.8_devdev_20130604-py3.3.egg/jinja2/bccache.py", line 163, in get_cache_key
    if isinstance(filename, unicode):
NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined`

I have WebOb 1.2.3 and distribute 0.6.45. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Jinja2 2.7.

`pip install jinja2==2.6` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be issues with the dev version of jinja2 that you are installing as they reimplement the python 3 port using a single codebase. I'd suggest going back to a previous release that is using 2to3.